# Undefined value when using paginate in get request using AJAX Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm doing get request using AJAX. In my Laravel Controller, I tried to use "->paginate(5);"
and I got undefined values but when I'm using "->get();" it works perfectly but I wanted to use paginate to have pagination in my table. I think there is an issue on how I output the values.
Get return an object and paginate return an array as per checking in console.
I'm using this "$.each(response.data, function (key, item)" to output the values. Please help.

This is my controller

```
public function getOrders($store_id)
{
    $data = DB::table('stores')
    ->where('stores.id',$store_id)
    ->paginate(5);

    return response()->json(['data' => $data]);

}
```

This is my AJAX

```
function fetchOrder(){
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/get-orders/"+store_id,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {

                if (response.data != null) {
                    console.log(response);
                    $('.OrderTbody').html("");
                    $.each(response.data, function (key, item) {
                        $('.OrderTbody').append('<tr><td>' + item.store_name + '</td></tr>');

                    });


                }
            }
        });
}
```

This is example output using paginate

[image]

This is the response in console using the get which is working

```
Object
data:
current_page: 1
data: [{…}]
first_page_url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/get-orders/2?page=1"
from: 1
last_page: 1
last_page_url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/get-orders/2?page=1"
links: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
next_page_url: null
path: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/get-orders/2"
per_page: 15
prev_page_url: null
to: 1
total: 1
[[Prototype]]: Object
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

and this is response in console using paginate that is NOT WORKING

```
{data: Array(1)}
data: Array(1)
0:
address: "Cubao, Quezon City, Metro Manila, Philippines"
approval: 1
close_time: "20:24:00"
created_at: "2022-03-21 12:22:18"
id: 2
lat: "14.6177663"
lng: "121.0571541"
open_time: "20:23:00"
profile_image: "support-1store-prof_image1647868469.jpg"
status: 1
store_name: "Kainan"
store_users_id: 3
updated_at: "2022-03-21 13:14:29"
zipcode: "3112"
[[Prototype]]: Object
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$.each(response.data.data, function (key, item) {
    $('.OrderTbody').append('<tr><td>' + item.store_name + '</td></tr>');
});
```

Comment: Sir @davit it works!! now I realized my mistake thank you so much

Comment: thank you so much sir @Hicham, can I ask again if it is okay, how can I use the paginate? because it it response from json how can I used the render or link for pagination

Answer (score 1):

try importing your data like this :

```
   $data = DB::table('stores')
    ->where('stores.id',$store_id)
    ->paginate(5)
    ->toArray();
```

adding `->toArray()` will simplify your objects so the JSON serialization will be more "easy" for the Laravel.

Comment: It worked ! thank you so much sir @Hicham, can i ask again if it is okay, how can I use the paginate? because it it reponse from json how can I used the render or link for pagination